# How do I slice a Pandas dataframe with a double column index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which Index is built with two columns, an Object and a Datetime.

How can I select Rows based on the value (composed) of the index?

Thank you

Creating Dataframe

```
data = pd.read_csv(("dados_meteo.csv"),\
               names=['POM','DTM','RNF','WET','HMD','TMP','DEW','INF'],\
               parse_dates = ['DTM'])
```

Converting Datetime

```
data['DTM'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DTM'], coerce = True)
```

Setting Index

```
data.set_index(['POM', 'DTM'])
```

I would like to have the rows from a specific datetime interval AND a specific POM

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Example data sets always help. It sounds like you want to slice with a `MultiIndex`.

Comment: I used to know the answer to this, it somewhere in my answer history.  It's a really fun one-liner

Comment: I've just edited to be more clear

Comment: @PhillipCloud - Are the changes on question clear enough?

Comment: frioMurteira = data.ix['Murteira']['2013-11-01 00:00:00':'2013-11-05 00:00:00'] is working